# grunt lesslint how to prevent output from being written to console

Tags: less, gruntjs

We are trying to use [grunt-lesslint](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/grunt-lesslint) in our project, as our UI developer is comfortable fix errors in less file. [grunt-recess](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/grunt-lesslint) seems more powerful but not sure if it can point errors in less file itself. I am unable to comprehend enough from lesslint page, and there do not seem to be many examples. Does anyone know the following:

1. How to prevent lesslint from displaying on the console. I use formatters and the report file is generated, but it also prints on console, which I do not want to.
2. How to make lesslint fail only in the case of errors (not warnings). Also csslint seems to report errors also, while lesslint mostly gives warnings only, why is that so? Does lesslint throw errors as well? How to make it fail only in case of errors?
3. I tried using 'checkstyle-xml' formatter, but it does not seem to use it (I have used in jshint and it gives a properly formatted xml, which it does not give for lesslint).
4. Is it possible to compile less (many files or directories) in conjunction with lesslint? Any example?

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd say it's more of a common practice to display stdout for this kind of thing; the JSHint plugin does it, as does any other linting plugin that I've used. If you get in another developer that uses Grunt they'll probably expect stdout too. If you really want to override this, use grunt-verbosity: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-verbosity
2. Again, this is a convention in Grunt; if a task has any warnings then it fails. The reason being if you lint a file and the linter flags something up it should be dealt with straight away, rather than delay it; six months time you have 500 errors that you haven't fixed and you're less likely to fix them then. Most linting plugins allow you to specify custom options (I've used CSS Lint and that is very customisable), so if you don't like a rule you can always disable it.
3. This should work. If there's a bug with this feature you should report it on the issue tracker, where it will be noticed by the developers of the plugin. https://github.com/kevinsawicki/grunt-lesslint/issues
4. Yes. You can set up a custom task that runs both your linter and compile in one step: something like `grunt.registerTask('buildless', 'Lint and compile LESS files.', ['lesslint', 'less'])`; note that you'll have to install https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less to get that to work. Also note that, failing linting will not compile your LESS files; mandate that your code always passes the lint check; you'll help everyone involved in the project.

Comment: Hi @Ben, workaround for 4 is good. Point 3 is no longer an issue except that the checkstyle results are not formatted. For point 1, when JSHint silently writes to output file, why can't LessLint and CssLint do so? I don't understand why you say writing to console is expected behaviour, especially if you have a formatter defined with a destination file. I am not convinced about point 2 though. Why should build/task fail for warnings (For errors it is correct)?

Comment: i. That's just how the plugin is written; likely JSHint was written by different people to CSS Lint, so they don't have the same exact functionality. ii. Grunt tasks often produce output on the console, which you can redirect to a file if you choose (this is again, standard practice). Running `grunt jshint --no-color > test.txt` will redirect all of jshint's output into a file instead of the console. iii. Again, standard practice. Ideally you should be fixing linting errors as and when the plugin finds them, and this is why they fail builds, to prevent bad code from being checked in to a repo.